# Laravel Lumen | Mail not registering correctly

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a current project which is using Lumen and requires to send mail.

I have set up and installed the latest version of Lumen (7) and also the latest version of `illuminate/mail`.

I have configure everything as per the documentation so I have the following:

```
$app->configure('mail');

$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Mail\Mailer::class);
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer::class);
$app->alias('mailer', Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\MailQueue::class);

$app->register(Illuminate\Mail\MailServiceProvider::class);
```

inside of my app.php and this is the following error that I keep getting when i do via `['mail']`:

> Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Factory] is not instantiable while building [Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel]

For the life of me I cannot figure out why this is and I have tried searching stack overflow and google but nothing seems resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am at the same point as you. It broke when I updated lumen from 6 to 7... probably something must be configured differently on 7

--EDIT--

i guess that is it... if you check  v6 docs:
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail

and v7 docs
https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/7.x/mail

they are different.

I will try this new config right now and get back here

-- EDIT 2 --

Yes, I can confirm that following the new configs described on the v7 docs, it works =)